# Are there C++ idioms that protect you from poorly ordered data members?

Tags: c++

Please consider the following case that would result in memory getting written after being deallocated.
The reason being that in `class PoorlyOrderedMembers` the member `m_pData` is declared after the member `m_nc` which means that the `std::unique_ptr` d'tor will be called and the instance of `ClassWithData` will be deleted just before the d'tor of `class NaughtyClass` will write to it.

While *writing* it, you could probably get hints for a problem if you try to put both member initializations in the initializer list and get an error or a warning. Alternatively, you could change `NaughtyClass` and `PoorlyOrderedMembers` to use `std::shared_ptr` but, these are only obvious after you know that there's a problem here.

What would be the tell that something is wrong here when reviewing the code after the mistake was already made?

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>


class ClassWithData
{
    char m_carray[32]{};
public:
    char* data() { return m_carray; }
    static constexpr size_t capacity() { return sizeof(m_carray); }
};

class NaughtyClass
{
    ClassWithData* m_p = nullptr;
public:
    ~NaughtyClass()
    {
        char const m[] = "d'tor called";
        memcpy(m_p->data(), m, sizeof m);
        static_assert(sizeof(m) <= ClassWithData::capacity(), "the string doesn't fit in the capacity");
    }
    void set(ClassWithData* p) { m_p = p; }
};

class PoorlyOrderedMembers
{
    NaughtyClass m_nc;
    std::unique_ptr<ClassWithData> m_pData;
public:
    PoorlyOrderedMembers() :
        m_pData(std::make_unique<ClassWithData>())
    {
        m_nc.set(m_pData.get());
    }
};


int main()
{
    PoorlyOrderedMembers poom;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that it's not the ordering that's the problem, but that you have a "naughty" class which just does bad things. It's more of a design problem than an implementation problem.

Comment: A yes/no question seems a bad fit for the site as well.

Comment: You have more to worry about : "useless use of pointers".  And other "C" style coding habits `char const m[] = "d'tor called";` -> `const std::string_view m{"d`tor called";`...  Using `memcpy` where a copy constructor can be used.  Looks like you're learning C++ from a source that's outdated and still teaches "C". As for your issue, there are enough compilers/static code analyzer tools  that can warn about incorrect order of initialization

Comment: Please note that the exaggerated nature of this example is intended to make the point obvious. You could imagine the same underlying issue in a more nuanced and less obviously avoidable scenario.

Comment: Surely the idiom is to *not* poorly order data members?

Comment: Thank you to all who commented, specifically about pointing out using `std::string_view`, I'll admit that I'm slow to adopt recent language/library features, but I'll get there. I would point out that the issue isn't "incorrect order of initialization", it's incorrect order of destruction. The online demo of the cppcheck static analyzer misses this bug. I'll have to check if others catch it. Any chance you'd be willing to give this a second look?

Comment: *"is anyone else mildly annoyed that char const m[] = "literal"; can't be written as auto m = "literal";..."* **I don't think so cuz once you understand how `auto works you'll automatically understand why that doesn't work as you expect it. `**

Comment: I suppose `auto& m = "literal"` is close enough.

Comment: @CplusPuzzle Yes, `&` will do the job.